# Java - import all audio files in directory, and concatenate

Tags: java, audio

I am working on a simple application which needs the facility to read in all the .wav files in a specified directory (/audiofiles), and then concatenate them. I have working code which gets the names of all the files in the directory and prints them to the console, and code which concatenates a list of specified files, but I cannot seem to combine the two functions. Any suggestions?

So far:-

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class getconc_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

            // get list of file names from audio directory

            File audDir = new File("/audiofiles");

           //define a list to contain the audio files names and path

              File[] filesList = audDir.listFiles();

           // assign contents of each wav file from filesList to a string           

                String wavFile1 = filesList.get(0);
                String wavFile2 = filesList.get(1);


          // read the string from the audio file into an AudioInputStream, and concatenate

            try {
                AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile1));
               AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile2));

               AudioInputStream appendedFiles = 
                        new AudioInputStream(
                            new SequenceInputStream(clip1, clip2),     
                            clip1.getFormat(), 
                            clip1.getFrameLength() + clip2.getFrameLength());

              AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles, 
                        AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, 
                        new File("wavAppended.wav"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by concatenate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have error in your codes

```
String wavFile1 = filesList.get(0);
String wavFile2 = filesList.get(1);
```

Should be replaced by

```
 String wavFile1 = filesList[0].getPath();
 String wavFile2 = filesList[1].getPath();
```

Secondly use

> new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(list)) to join multiple streams into one.
>   I have not added few checks in the program like checking the size and null check for clip object.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class getconc_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

            // get list of file names from audio directory

            File audDir = new File("/audiofiles");

           //define a list to contain the audio files names and path

              File[] filesList = audDir.listFiles();

           // assign contents of each wav file from filesList to a string           



          // read the string from the audio file into an AudioInputStream, and concatenate

            try {

                long length = 0;
                AudioInputStream clip = null;
                List<AudioInputStream> list = new ArrayList<AudioInputStream>();

                for (File file:filesList ) {
                    clip = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(file.getPath()));
                    list.add(clip);
                    length += clip.getFrameLength();

                }
            if(length>0 && list.size()>0 && clip!=null) {

               AudioInputStream appendedFiles =
                        new AudioInputStream(
                            new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(list)),
                                clip.getFormat(),
                                length);

              AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles, 
                        AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, 
                        new File("wavAppended12.wav"));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts - that's certainly an approach to build on. It does return a NullPointerException at line 29 though...

Comment: I have already mentioned in answer that you have to handle few edge cases for null. Nevermind i have edited my nswer to catch exceptions also

Comment: Working now! Interestingly, unlike my other script, this one does not appear to function with the absolute filepath, and when using the relative filepath, requires the removal of the "/" from the "/audiofiles" directory. Thanks for that...